# How is "1" defined in various branches of mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, arithmetic

Wikipedia does not elaborate much on the concept of "[One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%28number%29)" in such branches as graph theory, ring theory, algebra, topology, measure theory, formal logic, etcetera. How can one grasp the concept of "oneness" in diverse branches of mathematics?

Comment: It’s generally taken as a primitive concept not really requiring much discussion. What sort of elaboration do you have in mind?

Comment: Where does "1" appear in graph theory, topology, measure theory, or formal logic??

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Isn't $1:=\{\varnothing\}$ in all 'regular' mathematics?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In the link it says: 1 is " 
more generally, in abstract algebra, the multiplicative identity ("unity"), usually of a ring". So my question would be to list similar notions in all branches of mathematics?

Comment: @Mahmud Oh! That $1$!

Comment: Mahmud, that’s a statement about **notation**, not about the concept!

Comment: I thought _notation_ encapsulates _concept_?

Comment: Notation is merely a representation of a concept. A notation may represent more than one concept, and a concept may have more than one common notation. E.g., the identity of a group is represented both by $e$ and by $1$, depending on the taste of the writer.

Comment: In particular, the identity of an additive group is usually denoted by $\,0,\,$ not by $\,1.\:$ which seems a great challenge to the grand theory of "oneness". Hopefully not another $\, 0 = 1\,$ proof is forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

"One" is typically defined as $S0$ in Peano Arithmetic. $\forall x(Sx=x+S0)$ is a theorem of PA and much weaker theories of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The number $1$ has several unique properties. First, it is the neutral element with respect to multiplication, meaning that $1\cdot x = x$ for all $x$. This property is used in many algebraic structures to define a $1$.

Another unique property among non-negative integers is $1 \mid x$ for all $x$. This is used in order theory and lattice theory: An element is called the $1$-element if it is less or equal than all other elements.